# How to extend tag.object with new attributes within Adobe CQ5 TagManager API

Tags: aem

I want to extend tag.object (TagManager API) with new attributes. By default, every tag.object has three attributes: name, title and description. Is it possible? Has anybody deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own TagManager - probably extending the abstract TagManager interface and implementing it.

Have a look at the com.day.cq.tagging.impl package - especially the JcrTagManagerImpl class.

A workaround would be to wrap the tag object and encode the additional properties into the description field.